# How to drop invalid Java classes from Oracle?

Tags: oracle-11g, plsql, java

I tried to load some jars into my database, but I think I messed up something, because I tried as DBA and then with some oracle user... This was my first command:

```
call dbms_java.loadjava('-genmissing -jarasresource -v -force -grant MYSCHEMA ./some-jar-file.jar');
```

and then this:

```
call dbms_java.loadjava('-genmissing -v -force -grant MYSCHEMA ./some-jar-file.jar');
```

I think I also tried with and without MYSCHEMA, because my Java source had alway some errors regarding to this jars.

My problem is, that right now I have more than 1500 invalid Java classes and I don't know how to clean this mess up:

```
SELECT *
    FROM user_objects
    WHERE /*object_type like '%JAVA%'
    AND */status = 'INVALID'
```

I tried with this trick:

```
SET HEADING OFF SET FEEDBACK OFF SET ECHO OFF;

SPOOL delete-java-class.sql;

select 'drop java class "'||object_name||'";' from user_objects where object_type like '%JAVA%' AND status = 'INVALID';

SPOOL OFF;

SET HEADING OFF SET FEEDBACK OFF SET ECHO OFF;

SPOOL compile-java-class.sql;

select 'alter java class "'||object_name||'" resolve;' from user_objects where object_type like '%JAVA%' AND status = 'INVALID';

SPOOL OFF;
```

But the drop script wasn't able to drop these classes (approx. 5 of 1500 could be deleted), I got this error:

```
ora-29537: class or resource cannot be created or dropped directly
```

The recompile script was also not able to resolve the issue, but it was able to reduce the invalid count to 800.

Can someone give me some advice? :) Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using the dropjava procedure in [DBMS_JAVA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e10588/appendixa.htm#JJDEV13000)?

Comment: Yes, I executed the call dbms_java.dropjava() for every .jar with schema option, without, as -jarasresource as -jarsasdbobjects, but the invalid classes are still there

Comment: It looks like there's also a command-line version which you can run from the operating system.  Have you tried that? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e10588/cheleven.htm#JJDEV13372

Comment: Why would the command line version of dropjava behave differently... ? But I will give it a try, thank you.

Comment: It's the same. It's seems, that some of the jars are stuck or something like this, because the invalid java object count doesn't want to change :(

Answer (score 0):

[`drop java class <class_name>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/DROP-JAVA.html#GUID-0D24ADCD-01C8-4FB0-B14C-F5D9FB25E321)

If you have more than one invalid class, you could edit this script I wrote, changing the owner, to spool a file that you can then run. To spool the output, at the SQL*Plus prompt do:

```
spool dropit.sql;
select 'drop java class '||'"'||object_name||'"'||';' 
from dba_objects where object_type='JAVA CLASS' and status='INVALID' 
and owner='SCHEMA-OWNER';
```

Where `dropit.sql` is the filename containing your drop script.